# Which stream does Bash write its prompt to?

Tags: bash, command-line, prompt

I am trying to redirect all output from bash (prompt, user input, results) to a file

Example:

```
/bin/bash > file.txt 2>&1
```

I thought that would work, but I'm not getting the prompt. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Bash outputs the prompt only in interactive mode. I.e. it is normally output to the terminal (/dev/tty on linux). That is neither /dev/stdout or /dev/stdin :)

Now, I'm not sure but I can imagine that bash will allow limited interactive mode when there isn't a fully functional tty. In that case I'd *expect* the prompt to be written to stdout. I haven't tested that.

Nice Proof Of Concept:

```
(for a in some set of words; do echo $a > /dev/tty; done) 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

will just output 1..10 as if there wasn't redirection. Like the prompt, output is directly sent to the terminal (which will fail if there isn't one)

HINT: if you wanted everything to be collected look at

- [script(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) with scriptreplay ( [Capture the execution logs in SSH client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119823/capture-the-execution-logs-in-ssh-client/7119873) or [Scripts shell recording playback](https://superuser.com/questions/335796/scripts-shell-recording-playback/335870#335870) - this appears to be somewhat of a FAQ)
- the [PROMPT_COMMAND variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) which should allow you to print stuff to stdout as a sideeffect of displaying the prompt
- `set -o xtrace` (a.k.a. `set -x`, `bash -x` etc) for general logging of *statements*

Comment: Added hints on how to potentially get more bash output into a pipe

Comment: `seq` is a highly nonstandard external command, and shouldn't be used in this manner. If you're using `bash`, do something like `for x in {1..10}`, or `for ((x=1; x<=10; x++))` instead.

Comment: @Chris: good point, thanks for the heads up

Comment: This is incorrect. The prompt is written to stderr, i.e. file descriptor 2, whether that is a TTY or not. This is easy enough to verify: `bash -i > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt` and you'll see that the prompt is written to stderr.txt, not your terminal.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do it would be

```
bash -i >/tmp/logfile 2>&1
```

Bash will write everything to `/tmp/logfile` and keep executing commands as you type them, but nothing will be displayed in the terminal. You can make it exit just as you exit your terminal session - by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or typing `exit`.

Notice that if you run the same thing without `stderr` redirection, you will only have the greeting message logged to the file, all the rest will work in your current terminal. So the answer to your question about stream to which bash outputs its prompt (and all the following commands) seems to be: **stderr**.

<sub>Oh yes, and the `-i` parameter simply forces bash to run in interactive mode. Don't listen to those people - you don't need any magic tricks to do that ;)</sub>

Comment: +1 for use of `<sub>` to format. I just learned something new today. :D

Comment: thanks for the -i flag

Answer (score 5):

The prompt is written to stderr as truss (on Solaris here) shows:

```
$ truss -ft write -p 10501
10501:  write(2, " d", 1)               = 1
10501:  write(2, " a", 1)               = 1
10501:  write(2, " t", 1)               = 1
10501:  write(2, " e", 1)               = 1
10501:  write(2, "\n", 1)               = 1
10521:  write(1, " S a t u r d a y ,   S e".., 46)  = 46
10501:      Received signal #18, SIGCLD [caught]
10501:        siginfo: SIGCLD CLD_EXITED pid=10521 status=0x0000
10501:  write(2, " $  ", 2)             = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

To trick `bash` into thinking it's in interactive mode (although `stdout` is not being sent to a terminal) you may use the already mentioned `script` command.

```
(
exec 1> >(tee bashlog.txt) 2>&1
script -q /dev/null /bin/bash -l
)

# alternative without script command
(
# bash: no job control in this shell
exec 1> >(tee bashlog.txt) 2>&1
/bin/bash -il
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In interactive mode, bash outputs its prompt into stderr. The following strace command shows it (`--norc` option to make sure that ~/.bashrc which sets another prompt is not interpreted to overwrite my custom prompt):

```bash
$ export PS1="MYPROMPT> "
MYPROMPT> strace -f -- bash --norc 
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash"], 0x7ffcd83805b0 /* 59 vars */) = 0
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
[...]
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
[...]
write(2, "MYPROMPT> ", 10MYPROMPT> )              = 10 <----- prompt written into stderr (fd = 2)
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}
```

The same command with the redirection of stdout and stderr into a file shows that the prompt is not printed but the shell accepts the commands:

```bash
MYPROMPT> strace -f -- bash --norc > /tmp/shout 2> /tmp/sherr
date
```

Look at the files from another terminal. The content of *shout* is:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/shout
dim. 04 sept. 2022 16:19:24 CEST  <------- Result of the date command entered above
```

The content of *sherr* is:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/sherr
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "--norc"], 0x7ffe73ea5da8 /* 59 vars */) = 0
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
[...]
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7ffc43496b30)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
[...]
read(0,  <-------- No prompt is displayed
```

But if you do the same adding `-i` option to the bash command line:

```bash
MYPROMPT> strace -f -- bash --norc -i > /tmp/shout 2> /tmp/sherr
```

The prompt is displayed on stderr:

```bash
$ cat /tmp/sherr
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "--norc", "-i"], 0x7ffd8c1fa520 /* 59 vars */) = 0
[...]
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7ffe1a8465f0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
[...]
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=37, ws_col=155, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
[...]
write(2, "MYPROMPT> ", 10MYPROMPT> )              = 10  <------ Prompt displayed on stderr (fd = 2)
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}
```