# Why does ` exec 2>somefile` hang?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exec

Why does

```
exec >somefile
```

return immediately, while

```
exec 2>somefile
```

doesn't and hang on indefinitely? Thanks.

Comment: ... but fails to ask, let alone answer, why keyboard input appears to stop working, and thus the "hang".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't hang. If you're running interactively, and you look inside `somefile`, you'll see your prompt. STDERR is where bash writes the prompt to.

Comment: [Which stream does Bash write its prompt to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20826/44425)